# Выдает ошибку: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x668f5ee4"

Tags: c++

При компиляции программа выдает такую ошибку:

Первый этап обработки исключения в "0x00ad169d" в "kursovaya.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x668f5ee4".
Необработанное исключение в "0x00ad169d" в "kursovaya.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x668f5ee4".

Может кто-то видит ошибку? Глаз замылился

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Задание начальных параметров
    srand(time(0));
    // 15ons
    const int n = 5, m = 5; 
    int dloch = 0, sost, I, i, circles = 0;
    double l = 3.1, u = 2.1, dt = 0.001, t = 0, T = 10000, Ppz = dt*l, r, tob, Tob = 0;
    double tzk[n]={0};
    double tzoch[m]={0};
    double Q, A, L0 = 0, T0, k, Potk, Potkz, Pobsz, postz = 0, obslz = 0, otkz = 0;
    double t_next = 0;
    //Моделирование
    while (t < (T - dt))
    {
        circles++;
        //Задание состояний системы
        sost = 0;
        for (I = 0; I < n; i++)
        {
            if (tzk[i] > 0) { sost++; }
        }
        if (sost == n) { sost += dloch; }

        //Изменение времени пребывания СМО в состояниях с очередью
        if (sost > n)
        {
            for (I = 0; I <= sost - (n + 1); i++)
            {
                tzoch[i] += dt;
            } 
        }

        //Генерация поступления заявки и определение времени обслуживания заявки
        r = rand() % 1000;
        r = r / 1000;
        tob = ((-1) / u)*log(1 - r);
        //Определение поступления заявки
        if (t >= t_next)
        {
            postz++; //заявка поступила
            r = rand() % int(1 / dt);
            r = r / int(1 / dt);
            t_next = t + ((-1) / l)*log(1 - r);
            if (sost < n) //есть свободные каналы
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (tzk[i] <= 0) //помещение заявки на обслуживание в свободный канал
                    {
                        tzk[i] = tob;
                        Tob += tob;
                        obslz++;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            else
                if (sost < (n + m)) { dloch++; obslz++; } //помещение заявки в очередь
                else
                {
                    otkz++; //отказная заявка
                }
        }
        else
        {   //заявка не поступила
            if (dloch>0)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (tzk[i] == 0) //помещение заявки из очереди в свободный канал
                    {
                        tzk[i] = tob;
                        Tob += tob;
                        dloch--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //уменьшение времени обслуживания заявки в занятых каналах
        for (I = 0; I < n; i++)
        {
            if (tzk[i] > 0) tzk[i] -= dt;
            if (tzk[i] < 0) tzk[i] = 0;
        }
        t += dt;
    }
    //Расчёт показателей эффективности системы
    Potk = (otkz * dt) / T;
    Q = 1 - Potk;
    A = l*Q;
    for (I = 0; I < m; i++)
    {
        L0 += (I + 1)*tzoch[i] / T;
    }
    T0 = L0 / l;
    k = A / u;
    Potkz = otkz / postz * 100;
    Pobsz = obslz / postz * 100;
    //Вывод результатов
    cout << "T = " << T <<" dt =  "<< dt << endl;
    cout << "Number circles = " << circles << endl;
    cout << "The number of bids received = " << postz << endl;
    cout << "The number of served bids = " << obslz << " or " << Pobsz << "%" << endl;
    cout << "The number of rejected bids = " << otkz << " or " << Potkz << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Chance of a denial of service bid = " << Potk << endl;
    cout << "Relative bandwidth = " << Q << endl;
    cout << "Absolute bandwidth = " << A << endl;
    cout << "Queue length = " << L0 << endl;
    cout << "The average time spent in the bid queue = " << T0 << endl;
    cout << "The average number of occupied channels = " << k << endl;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Берете отладчик и пошагово выполняете программу, чтобы определить, где она "вылетает".

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что переменная `i` не инициализирована.

```
int dloch = 0, sost, I, i, circles = 0;
                        ^^
```

Поэтому она имеет неопределенное значение. В результате уже в этом цикле

```
   for (I = 0; I < n; i++)
    {
        if (tzk[i] > 0) { sost++; }
            ^^^^^^
    }
```

программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Но даже если бы переменная была инициализирована, вызывает сомнение, что ее значение перед входом в следующий цикл и обращение с помощью нее к элементам массива `tzoch` являются корректными.

```
    if (sost > n)
    {
        for (I = 0; I <= sost - (n + 1); i++)
        {
            tzoch[i] += dt;
            ^^^^^^^^
        } 
    }
```

Имейте в виду, что тому, кто будет читать ваш код, будет совершенно не понятно, что программа делает.